# "acf/load_field" Critical error upon saving/updating WooCommerce products

Tags: php, functions, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to prepopulate an ACF field called "upcoming_class_date" using "acf/load_field" but my code snippet returns a critical error upon saving/updating a product in WooCommerce. It goes back to normal when I reactivate the snippet after saving.

I'm really new to this and would like to know what I'm doing wrong? Below is a copy of my code snippet. Thanks!

```
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=upcoming_class_date', 'set_upcoming_class_date_to_acf');
function set_upcoming_class_date_to_acf($field) {
    global $product_object;
    $attr = $product_object->get_attribute('class-date');
    // Turn string attr into an array
    $attr = explode( ' | ', $attr );
    
    // Get WP Settings Local Time
    $wpLocalDateToday = current_datetime()->format('m/d/Y');
    
    // Get the closest class date from local date today
    function amet_get_closest_date($a, $b) {
            return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);
        }
        usort($attr, "amet_get_closest_date");

        foreach ($attr as $count => $dateSingle) {
            if (strtotime($wpLocalDateToday) <= strtotime($dateSingle))  {
                $closestDate = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($dateSingle));
                break;
            }
        }
    // Render value
    if( !isset($field['value']) ){
        $field['value'] = $closestDate;
        $field['disabled'] = 0;
        return $field;
    } else {
        $current_value = get_field('upcoming_class_date');
        update_field('upcoming_class_date', $current_value);
        return $field;
    }
}
```

Here's the error that I get from the logs

```
2023-06-21T01:43:06+00:00 Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_attribute() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\plugindev\wp-content\plugins\insert-headers-and-footers\includes\class-wpcode-snippet-execute.php(277) : eval()'d code:5
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\plugindev\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(308): set_upcoming_class_date_to_acf(Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\plugindev\wp-includes\plugin.php(256): WP_Hook->apply_filters(Array, Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\plugindev\wp-content\plugins\advanced-custom-fields\includes\acf-hook-functions.php(109): apply_filters_ref_array('acf/load_field/...', Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\plugindev\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(308): _acf_apply_hook_variations(Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\plugindev\wp-includes\plugin.php(205): WP_Hook->apply_filters(Array, Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\plugindev\wp-content\plugins\advanced-custom-fields\includes\acf-field-functions.php(58): apply_filters('acf/load_field', Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\plugindev\wp-content\plugins\advanced-custom-fields\includes\validation.php(331): acf_get_field('field_64912967e...')
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\plugindev\wp-content\plugins\advanced-custom-fields\includes\validation.php(206): acf_validate_values(Array, 'acf')
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\plugindev\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(308): acf_validation->acf_validate_save_post('')
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\plugindev\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\plugindev\wp-includes\plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\plugindev\wp-content\plugins\advanced-custom-fields\includes\validation.php(273): do_action('acf/validate_sa...')
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\plugindev\wp-content\plugins\advanced-custom-fields\includes\validation.php(171): acf_validate_save_post()
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\plugindev\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(308): acf_validation->ajax_validate_save_post('')
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\plugindev\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\plugindev\wp-includes\plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\plugindev\wp-admin\admin-ajax.php(188): do_action('wp_ajax_acf/val...')
#17 {main}
  thrown
2023-06-21T01:43:06+00:00 Snippet "ACF Prepopulate Upcoming Class Date" (#81) was automatically deactivated due to a fatal error.
```

Comment: `$closestDate` looks like it could be undefined.

Comment: Closed as questions about 3rd party plugins such as WooCommerce and ACF are offtopic here and not in this stacks scope. You should ask this either on stackoverflow or on the plugins support routes or in their dedicated communities and user groups

Answer (score 1):

The error is indicating that a method function (`get_attribute()`) is attempting to be called on a variable that is set to `null`. This means that the `$product_object` variable is not populated with an instance of a class that has a method definition for `get_attribute()`, but rather is `null`.

You'll need to figure some other way to get the current product object. If you're in the admin editing a product, then you can get the product ID from a query parameter, and create the object using `wc_get_product()`. If you're on the frontend looking at a single product, then you can get the product ID from `get_queried_object_ID()`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to see the issue coming from the filter `acf/load_field`. I fixed it by just replacing it with `acf/prepare_field`.

Comment: when you post an answer it's not a reply like a forum and the order changes as people vote up and down, try to put everything needed in your answer rather than relying on other peoples answers and the order they appear in. Remember this isn't a forum/message/conversation thread and stack exchange isn't a messageboard!